Spring Security XSRF token isn't generated consistently ... but periodically
this is my first request to the backend

this is my second request

and third it appears again

Observing the pattern I'm getting a feeling that its a feature... any expert opinion on this will have my infinite gratitude :) thank you...!

you only get a new XSRF cookie in response IF you don't already have an existing one (in Cookies)
